# Storing and fetching multiple paragraphs using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file

So I am working on a small project and using PHP/MySQL so far.
I wanted to know how do I go on storing very long text (let's say a user inputs a lot of paragraphs at once). Is using SQL for saving the text a good idea? Or should I save the huge amount of text using some other method instead?
Thanks!

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am currently using LONGTEXT to store the text. I just wanted to know if it's a good approach to store such amount of text in a db.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html - Reference this.

Comment: Yes, its fine. How many records will you have in your database?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to store long text in Mysql database, just make sure you use appropriate column type in mysql database:

**TEXT** -  Holds a string with a maximum length of 65,535 characters

**MEDIUMTEXT** - Holds a string with a maximum length of 16,777,215 characters

**LONGTEXT** - Holds a string with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 characters